# Perl - reading a file between two time stamps

Tags: perl, parsing, time, timestamp

I have a log file, which I want to read chunk by chunk as per time stamps (5 minutes of data, one at a time). Sample is

```
2014/04/24-23:29:20.003078-<String>
2014/04/24-23:29:32.003157-<String>
2014/04/24-23:29:33.004872-<String>
2014/04/24-23:29:43.005785-<String>
```

now I open the file and use the flip flop op to see if the line time stamp is between the 5 minutes. (I'll start with 2014/04/24-00:00:00 to 2014/04/24-00:05:00 for 1st chunk). But flip flop returns nothing. I am taking a DATE string as argument (like scr.pl 04/24/2014). My code is:

```
$curr = timelocal(0, 0, 0, (split /\//, $ARGV[0])[1], (split /\//, $ARGV[0])[0]-1, (split /\//, $ARGV[0])[-1]);
$currentTime = strftime "%Y/%m/%d-%H:%M:%S", localtime($curr); 
$curr += 300;
$nextTime = strftime "%Y/%m/%d-%H:%M:%S", localtime($curr);

    $file='Output.txt';
    open(INFO, $file) or die("Could not open  file.");
    foreach $line (<INFO>)  {
            print "$currentTime\n\n$nextTime";
            if (/$currentTime/../$nextTime/){
            $dataChunk = "$dataChunk\n$line"; #nothing gets added to $dataChunk
        }else{
              <DO SOME STUFF on DATACHUNK above>
            }
          }
     close(<INFO>);
```

Any ideas why there is nothing returned?

---

I am using the following code now. It works, but again its slow to what I expect .

```
$currentTime = timelocal(0, 0, 0, (split /\//, $ARGV[0])[1], (split /\//, $ARGV[0])[0]-1, (split /\//, $ARGV[0])[-1]);
$nextTime = $currentTime + 300;
            my $date = substr($line1,0,19); #2014/04/24-23:29:21
            my ($year,$mon,$mday,$hour,$min,$sec) = split(/[\s\/\-:]+/, $date); 
            my $time = timelocal($sec,$min,$hour,$mday,$mon-1,$year);
            if ($currentTime <= $time && $nextTime > $time)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use [Time::Piece](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Piece.html) along with [Time::Seconds](http://perldoc.perl.org/Time/Seconds.html) to work with the time stamp. It's a lot cleaner and easier to work with than raw parsing. Plus, it makes doing your output a bit more flexible.

I could never get the flip/flop operator to do what I want. Just use an `if` statement with the time range.

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl

use strict;
use warnings;
use feature qw(say);
use autodie;

use Time::Seconds;
use Time::Piece;

use constant {
    START_TIME          => "2014/04/24-23:25:29",
    TIME_PERIOD         => 5,
    TIME_FORMAT         => "%Y/%m/%d-%H:%M:%S",
};

my $start_time = Time::Piece->strptime( START_TIME, TIME_FORMAT );
my $end_time   = $start_time + ( ONE_MINUTE * TIME_PERIOD );

while ( my $line = <DATA> ) {
    chomp $line;
    my $time_string = $line;
    $time_string =~ s/\..*//;
    my $time = Time::Piece->strptime( $time_string, TIME_FORMAT );
    if ( $time->epoch >= $start_time->epoch
            and $time->epoch <= $end_time->epoch ) {
        say "$line";
    }
}

__DATA__
2014/04/24-23:29:20.003078-<String>
2014/04/24-23:29:32.003157-<String>
2014/04/24-23:29:33.004872-<String>
2014/04/24-23:29:43.005785-<String>
2014/04/24-23:30:43.005785-<String>
2014/04/24-23:31:43.005785-<String>
```

Answer (score 0):

Personal preferences about the use of the flip-flop operator aside here are some things I see.

1. Your regular expressions in the range flip-flop use the implicit `$_` loop variable but you've explicitly told the `foreach` loop to use `$line` instead. Since there is nothing in `$_` your flip-flop will always return false.
2. You're use of the flip-flop with regular expressions means it will start and stop returning true only when it finds lines have the exact times you're looking for. Your input argument `$ARGV[0]` doesn't allow you to specify the time, only the date. The closest you can get is to pass in "04/24/2014" which will yield `$currentTime == '2014/04/24-00:00:00'` and `$nextTime == '2014/04/24-00:05:00'`. These times won't match any of the lines in your example input. Your update uses `<=` and `>=` instead but it could still use the flip-flop operator. This is the kind of thing it was designed for.

There are more problems though so turn on strict mode and warnings by adding the following to the top of your code:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
```

Once you've done this you'll see a bunch of syntax errors and warnings. They should lead you in the right direction. Then, debug and **ask separate questions for each issue you encounter**.

Comment: Ok, this clears a lot about flip flop theory. But I am still lost on how to use regular expression in this case so flip flop can detect it ? I would really appreciate an example line or 2.

Answer (score -1):

I'm not sure what you think `// .. //` will do, but I assure you it's not what you want here.

`//` contains a regular expression, and `..` is the range operator.  This means your if statement is doing this:

Compare `$_` to a regex of `/$currentTime/`, and compare it to a regext of `/$nextTime/`, then returning a boolean value according to the scalar context use of the range operator:

> It is false as long as its left operand is false.  Once the left operand is true, the range operator stays true until the right operand is true, AFTER which the range operator becomes false again.

In your case, that means it will practically always return false, so the conditional is never executed.

What you need is to convert the time in each line into a meaningful time value, such as a unix epoch, or use the perl [DateTime](http://search.cpan.org/dist/DateTime/lib/DateTime.pm) family of methods to do your date comparison.

Comment: I was using awk like (awk '\$0>=from&&\$0<=to' from=\"$currentTime\" to=\"$nextTime\" Output.txt) and it worked. just want to use perl instead.

Comment: Okay, well, perl and awk are two entirely different beasts... so you'll need to update your syntax to use Perl.

Comment: Thats basically the very question. :) what kind of change would be required. I am a little lost.

Comment: Well, I'm not going to write your code for you, but I told you what kind of changes to do, and suggested a module to help you.  Did you read my answer? Did you look at that module?

Comment: I am neither expecting one. I cant use any modules which aren't installed already with the default perl installation. Anyways, thanks for the help. I am working with TIME::Local for now.

Comment: Then you can use my other suggestion.

Comment: @Flimzy you have only described the range function of the `..` operator which is actually two operators in one. In this scalar context it doesn't do what you're describing here. Check Range Operators in `perldoc perlop`.

Comment: @Flimzy: You may want to read about the what the [range operator](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Range-Operators) does when called in scalar context.  However, my pretty strong opinion is that any code using it in scalar context is maintenance-hostile and should be rewritten. :)

Comment: ...And I see that this was already mentioned while I was digging up the link.  I clearly need to remember to reload comments before commenting. :)

Comment: @benrifkah: I didn't even know about scalar context on that operator... answer updated, although it doesn't change the fundamental answer. :)